# Disable @types/node in tsconfig

Tags: javascript, typescript

Given my codebase needs to contain nodejs and browser code and therefore `@types/node` is installed inside `node_modules`.

The frontend code contains `setTimeout` calls - which would always return a `number` for the browser.

Unfortunately `@types/node` provides different typings and therefore it always shows the following type error:

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'Timeout' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
```

Is there any way to exclude or disable `@types/node` in my `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: You can create another tsconfig for your frontend directory and use `typeRoots` to specify what you want to include. See [doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types).

Comment: @Eldar that's what I did unfortunately it adds `@types/node` automatically although it is not in `tsconfig`

Comment: It says `If typeRoots is specified, only packages under typeRoots will be included.` Do you have another file that overrides your config or sth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `ReturnType<typeof setTimeout>` instead of `number` to avoid the issue.

Answer (score -2):

Isn't is in package.json file?

Obs: this file stay in the root of your project folder.

Comment: `@types/node` is a dependency of a dependency

Comment: I see... Then you must no delete him.

Can you tell me what is the dependence that uses him?

Comment: If you want to test delete this dependency, you can find him in package-lock.json.

I found the Docs of types/node, but I think you don't need this.